# complex SQL ranking / row number, ignoring specified types and resetting count

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

ACTUAL DATA

```
colA    group_date  type    desc        actual_date     
ABC123  1/15/2013   A       TEST1       1/17/2013       
ABC123  1/15/2013   B       TEST1       1/17/2013       
ABC123  1/15/2013   A       TEST2       1/19/2013       
ABC123  1/15/2013   I       IGNORE_1    1/22/2013       
ABC123  3/15/2013   B       TEST3       3/20/2013       
XYZ456  6/10/2012   A       XYZTEST1    6/12/2012       
XYZ456  6/10/2012   B       XYZTEST2    6/13/2012       
XYZ456  6/10/2012   A       XYZTEST2    6/13/2012       
XYZ456  10/1/2012   B       XYZTEST3    10/5/2012       
XYZ456  11/15/2012  B       XYZTEST4    11/18/2012      
SSS999  4/10/2011   A       SSSTEST1    4/13/2011       
SSS999  4/10/2011   B       SSSTEST2    4/14/2011       
SSS999  4/10/2011   A       SSSTEST2    4/14/2011       
SSS999  4/10/2011   A       SSSTEST3    4/19/2011       
SSS999  8/5/2011    B       SSSTEST4    8/7/2011        
SSS999  8/5/2011    I       IGNORE_SSS1 8/14/2011       
SSS999  11/5/2011   B       XYZTEST4    11/18/2011      
SSS999  11/5/2011   B       XYZTEST5    11/20/2011      
SSS999  12/15/2011  B       XYZTEST6    12/16/2011
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to get a ranking/row number for each group.  A unique row number (that should be incremented, partitioned?) consists of colA, group_date, desc (ordered by actual_date).  If "desc" and "actual_date" records are the same, the number should repeat, which I believe I can already get working.

My problem is that it should "reset" the count each time an "I" type record is encountered.  This "I" type record can be assigned a row_number of 0, or my preference would be have it omitted as it will be deleted from the table once the proper row number is obtained... it's there only for reference.

This is what I'm currently targeting (which includes the "I" records that CAN be deleted in final query):

TARGET RESULTS

```
colA    group_date  type    desc        actual_date     row_num
ABC123  1/15/2013   A       TEST1       1/17/2013       1
ABC123  1/15/2013   B       TEST1       1/17/2013       1
ABC123  1/15/2013   A       TEST2       1/19/2013       2
ABC123  1/15/2013   I       IGNORE_1    1/22/2013       0
ABC123  3/15/2013   B       TEST3       3/20/2013       1
XYZ456  6/10/2012   A       XYZTEST1    6/12/2012       1
XYZ456  6/10/2012   B       XYZTEST2    6/13/2012       2
XYZ456  6/10/2012   A       XYZTEST2    6/13/2012       2
XYZ456  10/1/2012   B       XYZTEST3    10/5/2012       3
XYZ456  11/15/2012  B       XYZTEST4    11/18/2012      4
SSS999  4/10/2011   A       SSSTEST1    4/13/2011       1
SSS999  4/10/2011   B       SSSTEST2    4/14/2011       2
SSS999  4/10/2011   A       SSSTEST2    4/14/2011       2
SSS999  4/10/2011   A       SSSTEST3    4/19/2011       3
SSS999  8/5/2011    B       SSSTEST4    8/7/2011        4
SSS999  8/5/2011    I       IGNORE_SSS1 8/14/2011       0
SSS999  11/5/2011   B       XYZTEST4    11/18/2011      1
SSS999  11/5/2011   B       XYZTEST5    11/20/2011      2
SSS999  12/15/2011  B       XYZTEST6    12/16/2011      3
```

Comment: “A unique row number ... consists of colA, group_date, desc”? No it doesn't, there are duplicates. “ordered by actual_date”? There are duplicate actual_dates. “each time an "I" type record is encountered”? Encountered in what order? Your ordering is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a query that works for your data:

```
with ignore_count as
(
  select *
    , ignore_count = (select count(1) from MyTable i
                    where t.colA = i.colA
                    and t.group_date > i.group_date
                    and type = 'I')
  from MyTable t
  where type <> 'I'
)
, ranks as
(
  select colA
    , group_date
    , type
    , [desc]
    , actual_date
    , [row_num] = dense_rank() over (partition by colA, ignore_count
                                   order by group_date, actual_date)
  from ignore_count
)
select *
from ranks
order by colA
  , group_date
  , [row_num]
  , type
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87160/14).

Here I've grouped by checking the number of `I` rows that occur prior to each row in the `colA` group to allow the `row_num` reset to occur, then I've used [DENSE_RANK](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to rank within each `colA` group, separated by the `I` rows.

You'll note I've removed the `I` rows to help with the query; you mentioned this was OK.

This *does* work for your data, but, as noted in a comment, this does seem like the requirements are quite complex, so the answer might not work for your entire dataset.

Hopefully it gets you on the right track and can be easily tweaked if required.

Comment: Amazing... after some light tweaking I was able to get it to work with my much larger recordset.  Any suggestions on books or websites that might help me better my t-sql programming with CTE, ranking and the likes?  I'm not sure I could have ever derived that query.  Thanks!